# Wordpress changed directory url / site broke permalinks and pages

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I changed my wordpress url and site url from "blog" to "extras". Now only the home page works. The post permalinks and pages go to a 404 page. Did I miss something in the change? How do I fix it? Thanks. New posts and pages also have the same issue.

I read somewhere that I need to check the .htaccess page but I can't find it. ... Or do I need to update something in the wp_config file?

Comment: did you mean you change `domain.com/blog/`  into  `domain.com/extras/ ` ?

Comment: yes. I moved the entire wordpress folder within my root folder from domain.com/blog/ into domain.com/extras/

Comment: Change your ` Site Address (URL) ` and ` WordPress Address (URL) ` in your general settings. Then save.. you may also need to open the permalinks setting and click save without need to make any changes on permalinks setting

Comment: Tried all that but to no avail.

Comment: the last suggestion I can give is export . download  your database , then search and replace `domain.com/blog/` into `domain.com/extras/` then dump your database , import with the new one.. Do  with your own risk : )

Comment: Already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search your whole database for a string /blog/ which was your previous directory and replace it with /extras/ which is your new directory. Use this search and replace script https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip

Download it and upload everything in your extras directory. Before putting it there rename it's unzipped directory name to snr. It will make easier to access the script. Now open http://example.com/extras/snr and at top put the strings as directed above and click run.

It will search the whole database and where it will find "/blog/" will replace it with "/extras/". Problem solved.